# check IPP is enabled or not in opencv

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0, intel-ipp

I have system with installed `opencv-3.0`. I need to check whether `IPP` is enabled or not in the opencv. How can I check that ?

Comment: Ipp is enabled in compilation time.  I don't think you can.  However you can compile opencv by yourself

Comment: there is a function to print all build parameters at runtime. But I dont remember the command atm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try `std::cout << cv::getBuildInformation() << std::endl;`

Answer (score 0):

Using Python:

```
import cv2
print(cv2.getBuildInformation())
```

(print command useful to get readable output on the command line).